# Non-Inverting Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, temperature, lm35

This circuit is for a temperature sensor with its output signal being amplified so as to be better processed.

What is the role of RI1 which is the input resistor of the non-inverting pin of the LM358.

[image]

Comment: Is there some special reason why your circuit runs from right to left?  Circuits are normally drawn with inputs on the left and outputs to the right.

Comment: No particular reason.

Comment: RI1 is going to introduce a DC error of anything up to 1 mV but it may be actually present to protect the input from some external over-voltage situation. However, that seems unlikely (given the direct connection to the LM35) so if you really want an answer you should ask the guy who designed it or read his/her technical write up on the circuit. While you are at it ask that person what RPS11 and 21 are all about. I get the feeling that it's a low accuracy design and poorly designed.

Comment: Rps11 and 21 are there in order to create an effective resistance of 75 ohms in order to create an rc damper. It is also available in the datasheet of the LM35 in the recommended circuits section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons for adding a resistor at the input of a non-inverting amplifier is to reduce the voltage offset in high-precision measurements, which is caused by its finite input resistances as described by [Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/4/4348.html) and [TI](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-040.pdf).

Essentially a op-amp has a very large, but finite input resistance (e.g. LM358 has a common-mode impedance of \$4M\Omega||1.5pF\$), and consequently some current flows into the inputs.

It is described more in detail in the [Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/4/4348.html) application note, but here is what might happen if the input resistor is not used:

- Consider that no resistor is used and that \$V^+\$ is tied to ground. By doing so, the input resistance of \$V^+\$ if being shorted to ground, thus not playing any role anymore.
- Disregarding that the input/output common mode voltage for the moment, the feedback would force the inverting input \$V^-\$ to match the \$V^+\$ voltage.
- Since the voltage across \$R_{P1}\$ in this case would be zero, no current flows through it.
- Replacing now the input resistance with a current source, and solving for the output voltage, yields

$$V_{out}=R_{S1}\cdot I_{R,V_{IN^+}}$$

This means that even if the non-inverting input was to be shorted, some output voltage would appear. This problem can be mitigated by adding a resistor in the non-inverting input with a value approximated to:

$$R_{V_{IN^+}}= R_{S1} || R_{P1}$$

The entire derivation can be found in the links provided.